# How check if id exist in database before return?

Tags: php, laravel

**Before looking for a page I wanted to check if the id exists, so if I don't find it, give up looking I tried as follows:**

> My controller product

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    if($produto = Produto::find($id)) {
        return view('produtos.show', compact('produto', 'id'));
     }
   // $search_results=Produto::findOrFail($id);

    return 'Not found';


}
```

->My Route->

```
Route::get('/produtos/editar/{id?}','App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@search')->name('searchproduct');
```

->My Blade Form

```
      <form id="search" method="GET" action="{{ route('searchproduct') }}" >
    <input id="q" name="q" type="text" /></br>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" >Alterar</button>
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

->My Jquery Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("form#search").on('submit',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var q = jQuery("#q").val();
          window.location.href = jQuery(this).prop('action')+"/" + encodeURIComponent(q)
     });
});
```

> How can i check in database before? send It's always going to the default 404 page

Comment: There's an `exists()` method, but `findOrFail()` should also work. It'll trigger a 404 immediately, so you never hit that `if ($search_results)` check, and you also don't need it at all. Does something not work with your current code?

Comment: @TimLewis I just want to print the error without it sending it to the standard error page of laravel, understand? like : "hey man this not exist in first place"

Comment: @TimLewis I'll give more context is an input that puts the route for example :products/List/{id?}

Comment: Then don't use `findOrFail()`; like I said, that immediately triggers a 404 redirect. If you're using `{id?}`, then your method should be `public function search(Request $request, Produto $produto = null)`, or `public function search(Request $request, $id = null)`. Read the documentation on how URL parameters work; one of those will be an automatic 404 if the model isn't found, the other will need to be queried manually, like `Produto::findOrFail($id);`, or `if (Produto::where('id', $id)->exists()) { // hey man, this doesn't exist }`.https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: use ``find()`` instead of ``findOrFail()`` and rest it should work. ``$search_results = Produto::find($id);``

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to check $search_results variable. I changed findOrFail with find because findOrFail may throw an error.

```
public function search(Request $request) {
  $search_results = Produto::find($request->input('id'));

  if ($search_results == NULL) {
    abort(404);
  }

  return view('produtos.show', ['produto' => $search_results, 'id' => $request->input('id')]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to show a 404 page use this code :

```
public function search(Request $request)
{   
    //if not found it will trigger 404 not found page
    $produto = Produto::findOrFail($id = $request->input('id'));

    //otherwise it will return the view of produtos.show
    return view('produtos.show', compact('produto', 'id'));
}
```

or you can use this code too to use a custom return

```
public function search(Request $request)
{   
    $id = $request->input('id');
    if($produto = Produto::find($id)) {
       return view('produtos.show', compact('produto', 'id'));
    }

    //otherwise return your error view or message
    return 'Not found';
     
}
```

-> your route must be get not post

```
Route::get('/produtos/editar/{id?}','ProdutosController@search')->name('searchproduct');
```

-> no need for @csrf for get method

```
<form id="search" method="GET" action="{{ route('searchproduct') }}" >
    <input id="q" type="text" /></br>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" >Alterar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its not working it always going to the same error page , i tink i

Comment: and its always going not found even if exist

Comment: @JhonPeter make sure that your route exists then and u passing id parameter correctly through url

Comment: the id in the browser is correct

Comment: keep giving me the error " Attempt to read property "Nome" on null"

Comment: your route must be get not post

`Route::get('/produtos/editar/{id?}','ProdutosController@search')->name('searchproduct');`

Comment: its stoping give the error not found and go to 404 not found error pattern

Answer (score 0):

Also yo can use:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
  $search_results = Produto::where('id', '=', $request->input('id'))->first();

  if ($search_results == NULL) {
    abort(404);
  }

  return view('produtos.show', ['produto' => $search_results, 'id' => $request->input('id')]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about it:

exists:

```
if (Produto::where('id', $id)->exists()) {
    $search_results=Produto::find($id);
}
```

findOr:

```
$search_results = Produto::findOr($id, function () {
    // whatever you want to do if no record is found
});
```